# Wave Function Collapse of an Electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wavefunction, wavefunction-collapse

Given that if you make two observations of an electron's position in quick succession, the electron will be in the same place. Is there a time frame for how long it will stay in the same position (possibly some multiple of Planck time) and if so, would the wave function spread out again from the observed place or from a different spot following the momentum the electron previously had?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how accurate you measure the position; with the Heisenberg uncertainty, $\Delta p\,\Delta x\geq \hbar/2$: if you measure the position very accurately the first time ($\Delta x\approx 0$), then the momentum (velocity) will be very uncertain ($\Delta p\rightarrow\infty$) and you won't find the same position on the second measurement.

By the way, the Planck time doesn't really have to do with this.